# Check if unique value exists before updating in MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, exists, unique-constraint

I have a table containing a list of MAC addresses that in some cases has been padded to twelve digits and in other cases has not.

ie: 00FF12345678 OR FF12345678

There are cases where both values exist in this table.  I have a function that pads the value with the two zeroes and I can count the occurrence of these duplicates, but I don't have the time or patience to manually remove the duplicates or pad those that do not already have a record.

I figured I could update the 10 digit values to their correct value with the following statement:

```
UPDATE [rs_DEVICES]
SET [device] = dbo.pad_zero(12,[device])
WHERE LEN([device]) < 12
```

Of course this doesn't work because I need to only update those values that do not have an existing 12 digit record.  The unique constraint on this column stops me from doing this.

I need some sort of IF EXISTS statement in the WHERE clause but I haven't been able to come up with anything that works.

Using MSSQL Server 2008 R2.

Thoughts?

Comment: add a unique index on the column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does the job for you:

```
UPDATE [rs_DEVICES]
SET [device] = dbo.pad_zero(12,[device])
WHERE LEN([device]) < 12 AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM rs_DEVICES r1 WHERE r1.device = dbo.pad_zero(12,[device])
)
```

I think it's self explanatory, but if you have any questions please comment.

Honestly though, I recommend you to fix the real problem. Reassign the current references to the `length=10` records to their respective `length=12` siblings and then remove them.

Comment: I agree, although the unique constraint on this field was preventing me from updating the 10 character values to 12 characters as this would end up creating a duplicate.

Once the non-duplicate records were converted to 12 characters, I can now easily remove their 10 digit counterparts :)

Comment: That's what I meant. First, reassign all FKs to the correct records and then remove the `length=10` records. No need to update on this case.